# Create dictionary from list of variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to create a dictionary without writing the key explicitly.
I want to create a function that gets the number of variables and creates a dictionary where the variable names are the keys and their values are the variable values.

Instead of writing the following function:

```
def foo():
    first_name = "daniel"
    second_name = "daniel"
    id = 1
    return {'first_name':first_name, 'second_name':second_name}
```

I want to get the same result with function :

```
create_dict_from_variables(first_name, second_name)
```

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You cannot do this.

Your function could be defined as:

```
def create_dict_from_variables(first_name, second_name):
    return something_from(first_name, second_name)
```

and you can call this function:

```
create_dict_from_variables('abcd', 'efgh')
```

These two arguments `'abcd'` and `'efgh'` are not named variables.

Comment: Incorrect (see answer by Vasus) and unhelpful.  See pythonic answer by Not_a_Golfer.

Answer (score 32):

You can't do it without writing at least the variable names, but a shorthand can be written like this:

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> bar = 2
>>> d = dict(((k, eval(k)) for k in ('foo', 'bar')))
>>> d
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

or as a function:

```
def createDict(*args):
     return dict(((k, eval(k)) for k in args))

>>> createDict('foo','bar')
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

you can also use `globals()` instead of `eval()`:

```
>>> dict(((k, globals()[k]) for k in ('foo', 'bar')))
```

Comment: The `d = dict(((k, eval(k)) for k in ('foo', 'bar')))` works for me, but only on the command line or in a script. As soon as I put it in a function, it fails, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: To clarify (the comment edit box timed out on me), the dict() command fails with "NameError: name 'a' is not defined", even though just above I have a print() that produces the output "a is [1, 2] of type <class 'list'>". I have defined `a = [1,2]` and `b = [10,20,30]` and `keys = ['a','b']` and attempted to define d with `d = dict(((k, eval(k)) for k in keys))`. So why does this run on the command line, but not when it is enclosed in a function? Is this a scope thing?

Answer (score 27):

`pip install sorcery`

```
from sorcery import dict_of

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = dict_of(a, b, c)
print(d)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: its saviour, looking for this desperately. now easy to log any variables easily and see them

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), but I would recommend against it. Do it explicitly.

```
>>> import this
[...]
Explicit is better than implicit.
[...]
```

Your code will generally be better, more predictable, less prone to breaking and more comprehensible if you do it explicitly.

Comment: Thought about locals, but i dont want to pass around many temp variables

Comment: @user1087310: well then, you've thought about the only possibility that there is. Now that you have discarded that, know that there is no way of doing it; do it explicitly and enjoy!

Comment: It has been a long time since i tackled something that i cant do in python. I'm writing few functions that need to return bulk of parmeters for other functions. the returned dictionary is almost identical to the variables names, so i have high chance to make typo when i write the key explicitly. But my grandfather told me once that life is not easy :)

Comment: @Chris Morgan I'm sorry, but why not locals? It looks ideal here - function need to form a dict from variable names and values, which are in the function. I was looking for something like this to create a dictionary for passing into the sql query to substitute named placeholders from function parameterss, and it seems to do right what I need. So why not? Anyway I have variables inside function and have to create such dict manually without locals

Comment: @Arleg: `locals()` makes your code less predictable, more prone to breaking and less comprehensible, because implicit is worse than explicit. (It’s not immediately obvious what it does, and because of this non-obviousness it’s easy to mess up by unintentionally adding or removing from the return value.)

Answer (score 3):

In principle this is possible by passing variable names to function `create_dict` and then reaching to a caller stack frame from within `create_dict` function using module `inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, because Python functions don't get information about the variables used to *call* the function. Also, imagine doing something like this:

```
create_dict_from_variables(first_name[:-3] + "moo", last_name[::2])
```

The function will have no way of knowing the expressions used to create the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting solution to this problem, which **doesn't** involve external libraries. However, a slightly different syntax is needed: `eval(f(a,b))`

```
# Auxiliary Function
f = lambda s: f"dict({ ','.join( f'{k}={k}' for k in s.split(',') ) })"

first_name  = "daniel"
second_name = "joe"
D           = eval(f('first_name,second_name'))

print(D)
# {'first_name': 'daniel', 'second_name': 'joe'}
```

In the example above, the main goal of the OP is still accomplished, in the sense that we only type the names of the variables once to create a dictionary. However, the syntax is still a bit verbose.

PS. One important benefit of the code above is that we evaluate the dictionary in its original namespace, which removes any restrictions with respect to the scope of the function (globals(), locals(), etc.). This was my main motivation behind using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**In fact, there is a way:**

```
from varname import nameof

def foo(first_name,second_name):
    return {nameof(first_name):first_name, nameof(second_name):second_name}

first_name = "daniel"
second_name = "daniel"

print (foo(first_name,second_name))
```

Output:

```
{'first_name': 'daniel', 'second_name': 'daniel'}
```

You can get the `python-varname` package below:

https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname

Basic use:

```
from varname import nameof

s = 'Hey!'

print (nameof(s))
```

Output:

```
s
```