# Create dictionary where keys are variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I quite regularly want to create a dictionary where keys are variable names. For example if I have variables `a` and `b` I want to generate: `{"a":a, "b":b}`  (typically to return data at the end of a function).

Are there any (ideally built in) ways in python to do this automatically? i.e to have a function such that `create_dictionary(a,b)` returns `{"a":a, "b":b}`

Comment: `"a":a` doesn't make much sense, `a` is going to get replaced by its value.

Comment: While there are certainly ways to do this (using `locals()`), I think this is very rarely a good solution. In the example you gave (returning multiple values from a function), consider returning a `namedtuple` from the collections module.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A place where one may use this regularly is in Django context data that gets passed to html templates. It makes sense to have `{"a":a, "b":b}` where the variable names in your views are the same as in the templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create dictionary from list of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495262/create-dictionary-from-list-of-variables)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered creating a class?  A class can be viewed as a wrapper for a dictionary.

```
# Generate some variables in the workspace
a = 9; b = ["hello", "world"]; c = (True, False)

# Define a new class and instantiate
class NewClass(object): pass
mydict = NewClass()

# Set attributes of the new class
mydict.a = a
mydict.b = b
mydict.c = c

# Print the dict form of the class
mydict.__dict__
{'a': 9, 'b': ['hello', 'world'], 'c': (True, False)}
```

Or you could use the `setattr` function if you wanted to pass a list of variable names:

```
mydict = NewClass()
vars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for v in vars: 
    setattr(mydict, v, eval(v)) 

mydict.__dict__
{'a': 9, 'b': ['hello', 'world'], 'c': (True, False)}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own function for `create_dict`

```
def create_dict(*args):
  return dict({i:eval(i) for i in args})

a = "yo"
b = 7
print (create_dict("a", "b"))
```

Which gives `{'a': 'yo', 'b': 7}` output.
Here's a simple generator for the same:

```
vars = ["a", "b"]
create_dict = {i:eval(i) for i in args}
```

or you can use this one-liner lambda function

```
create_dict = lambda *args: {i:eval(i) for i in args}
print (create_dict("a", "b"))
```

But if you want to pass the variables to the function instead of the variable name as string, then its pretty messy to actually get the name of the variable as a string. But if thats the case then you should probably try using `locals()`, `vars()`, `globals()` as used by [Nf4r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6335503/nf4r)

Comment: ["Is using eval in Python a bad practice?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice), usually `eval` should not be the go-to tool.

Comment: its no problem in this case at all.

Comment: Do note that **literal** eval will not even work, since names are not literals.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't, maybe should stick with `eval` i guess.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem to use `eval` at-least in the above case.

Comment: Its really not great to say its "bad" to use it, I believe all languages (atleast  the one that i use) are made with a really brilliant architecture, so to say that some function is not good to use, it wouldn't have been there in the first place, with all due respect I think everything, if used properly, is an asset in some way, so to say `eval` is dangerous, where I'll say its strong function to be used with care, that's all, its not bad.

Comment: You proved yourself why `eval` is dangerous with the "use `literal_eval` here for less risk" shenanigans: it is hard to sanitize input to eval. It might prove safe in this **very** particular case, but people tend to throw it around like it's the next best thing since sliced bread, and at some point it will receive uncontrolled input. There are valid use cases for eval, but this is not one. OP should either use `locals()` or preferably rethink their approach entirely. So: no, `eval` in itself is not bad, but most of the recommendations to use it are.

Comment: Not to mention that none of your examples work for function scope variables, which seemed to be what OP was after.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on the code of @Nf4r, I use something like:

```
a, b = 1, 2

def make_dict(*args):
    # Globals will change of size, so we need a copy
    g = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if not k.startswith('__')}  

    result = {}
    for arg in args:
        for k, v in g.items():
            try:
                if v == arg:
                    result[k] = v
            except ValueError:
                continue  # objects that don't allow comparison

    return result

make_dict(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this solution here. It seems to be inefficient though as it searched globals. Is there any better solution that you may have come across?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
a, b, c, d = 1, 2, 3, 4
dt = {k:v for k, v in locals().items() if not k.startswith('__')}
print(dt)
{'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: but if i have a lot of variables already defined prior, then it will show too many

Answer (score 1):

```
vars = ['a','b','c']
dict = {v : eval(v) for v in vars}
```

or

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 22 
# we aim to have d = {var1,var2} == {var1: 'var1', var2: 'var2'}
d = {
  f'{var1=}'.split('=')[0] : var1,
  f'{var2=}'.split('=')[0] : var2,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code ‍ snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation ‍](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future , and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Python variables as keys to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3972872/5178795)

I think the simplest version might be:

```py
fruit_dict = dict(apple=apple, banana=banana, carrot=carrot)
```

Comment: ifonly we could do  > d = dict(var1,var2)  # then we have d['var1'] == var1