# elegant way to fill dictionary with variables in python

Tags: python

I'm searching for an elegant more generic way to fill a dictionary with variables:

```
dic = {}
fruit = 'apple'
vegetable = 'potato'

dic['fruit'] = fruit
dic['vegetable'] = vegetable
```

is there a more generic way without using the variable-name in quotes ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972872/python-variables-as-keys-to-dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the quotes are the problem, how about this?

```
fruit = 'apple'
vegetable = 'potato'

dic = dict(
    fruit = fruit,
    vegetable = vegetable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be a very elegant solution but you could use `locals()` for retrieving the variables and then convert them into a dictionary.

```
fruit = 'apple'
vegetable = 'potato'
dic = {key:value for key, value in locals().items() if not key.startswith('__')}
```

This results in `{'vegetable': 'potato', 'fruit': 'apple'}`

However, I believe a better option would be to pass the variable names and create a dictionary as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818967/7255359):

```
def create_dict(*args):
  return dict({i:eval(i) for i in args})

dic = create_dict('fruit', 'vegetable')
```

Edit: Using `eval()` is dangerous. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/7255359) for more information.

Comment: You really shouldn't be recommending using `eval`, *especially* when it is being used to evaluate input to a function.

Comment: Absolutely! Using `eval` is dangerous, I believe the answer I linked to which uses `eval` assumes that the input `i` is sanitized and checked before running through the `eval()`