# Returning a function with dynamic variable names for use in e.g. lmfit

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions, data-fitting, lmfit

How to best return a function with dynamic variable names?
Usually one should avoid it.
But due to external package constraints this might not always be possible. E.g. [LMFit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) uses explicit variable names to adress parameters of the model.

If the function is

```
def (x, y):
    return y*x
```

then one **needs** to adress the parameter by its explcit name `y`.

For complex, generic fitting models one might need to dynamically generate a model with different parameters e.g.:

```
def make_model(x, myDict):
    
    ...
    def myModel(x, V1, V2):
        ...
        ...
        return result

    return myModel
```

In this example I want to change the names of the variables `V1` and `V2` to e.g. the keys of `myDict`. Is this possible? Should one do this at all and if not, how else do I create a function with exchangable variable names for use in such packages?
I do not want to keep them to be called `V1` and `V2` because when adressing them later (and when having > 5 parameters) it might be clumsy to keep track of the names for the user.

Comment: there's a very [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818733/create-dictionary-where-keys-are-variable-names) that should give you what you need.

Comment: @BLimitless I think i want to do the reverse. not create a dictionary from variables, but create variables from a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

The short answer is "No".  The `lmfit.Model` class inspects the model function to determine parameter names.  This is an important feature that is an advantage to the user: Parameters should be named and not put in some syntactically-important but semanitically meaningless order.

You could use something like `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.  For that, variables are  are reduced from parameter objects with attributes to floating point values that *must* be in a consistent but ultimately meaningless order. There are other reasons to avoid `curve_fit`, but this poor abstraction of "fitting parameter" is really unfortunate - it's like the authors forgot they were using Python and thought they were writing Fortran77.

Or you could use `lmfit.minimize` and write your own objective function (for curve-fitting, just returning "(data-mode)/uncertainty").  With that interface, you pass a `lmfit.Parameters` object - essentially a (ordered) dictionary of Parameter objects that you then unpack in your objective function.

> Should one do this at all and if not,

I would say "probably not" and than you should not name Parameters `V1`, `V2`, etc unless that is meaningful to you and the person working with the results.   If you told me that `V1` is 100.2 and `V2` is 0.75, I would say "oh, ok...".  OTOH, if you told me `Volume1` is 100.2 and `Velocity2` is 0.75, now I'm starting to understand.  Names matter.

> how else do I create a function with exchangable variable names for use in such packages?

Build functions with named Parameters and then keep track of them.