# Provide standard data to Flask template

Tags: python, templates, flask

I would like to be able to generate a navbar based on an object's contents, basically having a navbar array or class that holds subpages and generates the appropriate navbar with collapsing parts etc. I have experience with Laravel in PHP which is similar to Flask but I can't figure out a way to do it easily. I would have to provide a set of data objects to every single page since it's part of the layout but would prefer not to have to specify it specifically for each page. Is there a way to do this?

So far I only have the basics, an app factory, view and blueprint:

Factory

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    app.register_blueprint(blueprint_index)

    return app
```

Blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, session

blueprint_index = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__)


@blueprint_index.route('/')
def index():
    if 'text' in session:
        session['text'] += 1
    else:
        session['text'] = 0
    return render_template('pages/index.html', text=str(session['text']))
```

Ignore the little bit of debug text I added to the route.

Comment: Totally a job for [context processors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336023/2052575).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a context processor.  Add this to the end of your blueprint code-block:

```
@blueprint_index.context_processor
def inject_text():
    return dict(text=session['text'])
```

`{{text}}` will now be available within every template on that blueprint.