# Environment Variables in Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, environment-variables

So I have an angular 2/4 app, with a node `server.js` to serve it. I want to access an environment variable (backend endpoint is `localhost` for dev and another endpoint for prod). If it matters, this app (as well as the backend app) are meant to be deployed to Heroku.

I have tried finding a solution to this, but everything I found seems to lead to using multiple `environment.ts` files (1 for each configuration), and then swapping between them based on the `ng build` flag `--env`. But I am apprehensive about this solution as it seems to mix configuration and source code. I also would like to avoid (if possible) being required to re-build/re-deploy whenever an endpoint/config changes.

In Spring Boot, I'm used to using config like `${PORT:8080}` in the properties files. Though I've also created multiple `.properties` files in the past so I understand that sometimes it's just simpler/cleaner to do so.

In node, I'm used to doing env variables like `process.env.PORT || 8080`. Since my angular app is served by a node server.js, I would think I should be able to do something similar. But when I try using `process.env` in my `environments/environment.ts` file, I get the error `Cannot find name 'process'.`

So my question is essentially, if I am required to create multiple `environment` property files or is there an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help at all? [Environment Variables TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40622116/691711)

Comment: not really. but ty

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two choices, regardless of whether your config is stored in environment variables or in a config file on the server. Your clientside code needs it, so you either need for serve it as part of your assets bundle, or you have to fetch it as a separate request. That separate request could be an Ajax call or just a js file that gets served separately from the rest of the bundle.

I think ideally, the only difference between the production app and the nonproduction app on the client should be the data, the bundle density (in dev you don't want your stuff minified for example) and what url it's served from. Everything else should be discoverable from the source url, imo