# Creating a configurable library in JavaScript (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently creating a library which internally uses axios. Since I'm making use of dependency injection, I can't use the constructor for my services to initialize some data.

There are many ways to solve this in another way, e.g.

```
serviceWithOptions = container.Resolve(...);
serviceWithOptions.option1 = '';
serviceWithOptions.setOption2('');

..// etc
```

What I want to do instead, is something like `tsconfig.json`, `webpack.config.js` or `eslintrc.json`

I want users of my library to create a config file, which is parsed by my library and then internally use these things.

Now, I could just create a fileReader that reads a specific file, however, I don't know what will happen if users have my library as a `node_module` (the default way), since then, the root folder will be different?

Also, I found some libraries

- https://github.com/henrikjoreteg/clientconfig -> However, this one reads it from a cookie and is for the communication between client and node server, whereas I need a config for a library inside another library (like webpack, etc.) and thus, don't have any cookies
- Environment variables, however, [Environment Variables TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622116/environment-variables-typescript) this doesn't seem to be possible?
- https://github.com/mozilla/node-convict -> Looks like it's only for NodeJS
- https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config -> Like above, looks like it's only for NodeJS

What would be the best way and the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain, but I think this isn't really doable in the way you might hope. The comparison things you offer are actually not running as a library within a program, but actually executed as their own executables outside of the program. In a sense, for them, the program is merely data being provided.

And given that it seems to be an HTTP library you'd want a program to consume like any other, this would seem to introduce a lot of challenges.

Of course, yes, you could ask users to provide data via the `ENV` as a means to circumvent this, but perhaps there is another way to provide the config?

In what way are you using DI? Is there perhaps a means by which a config object can be provided and then return some constructor that is created within a closure where it has access to that config object?

Comment: Hm, okay. Sad. I was so used to do it this way from other pgoramming languages, that I thought it's easily do-able in JS as well.

I'm using InversifyJS and you can use factories to create certain services from a specific configuration. But this would require the container, so to access the container, I would need to export it, which I wouldn't want to do (doesn't sound like good practice to me, to give the end-user the container). 

So, seems like I will simply create setter methods to set configuration values and throw an error, if no option has been passed. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you envision as being exported by your module? The constructed container? All the services it creates?

Comment: Currently, I'm simply importing the container in my `index.ts` and then resolve the services, but not all, only the ones to be used by the end-user and then I'm simply exporting the created services. So the end-user would just get `PageClient` for example, but not `HttpClient` or `Container` etc.

Comment: A pattern I've used in my own projects that works somewhat similarly, but does require a bit of user level work, but not terribly much is something like this.

User imports a "make services" function from a module, that doesn't expose any of the internals. Just takes a config object and returns a set of services made by that.

And then the user imports their own module that exports the constructed values. Essentially they have a module as config.

It's a bit boilerplatey but not too but, and easily documentable.

Comment: Yeah, this is something I could imagine. Maybe a class called `ClientConfiguration` which I add in a SingletonScope, so all other services using this service get the same configuration. I think I would do it that way. Thanks for your input :)