# Passing parameter(s) to Javascript file from Python Flask app through HTML

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am building a Python/Flask based web app. The python script produces a dictionary of words and their corresponding weights. I have a javascript file (let's call it `custom.js`), which I call from the output.html. The way this javascript works is that it takes this dictionary and then uses `d3.v3.min.js` and `d3.layout.cloud.js` to create a wordcloud. When the dictionary is hard-coded into `custom.js`, the output file shows the wordcloud. However, the dictionary values will change depending on other parameters in the python script. Therefore, I would like to pass this dictionary from Python to `custom.js`. I am not sure how to do that.

I know that the parameters could be passed to HTML using `{{ params |safe }}`, but I am trying to figure out how to do that so that `custom.js` will receive the parameters (dictionary of words and weights, in this case) and word clouds can be rendered dynamically.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on @Nurzhan's suggested link, I modified the app.py code as: ```tps = [ {'text': 'even', 'size': 180}, {'text': 'great', 'size': 49}]
       return render_template('results3.html',tps=tps)```.  Added a function to my `custom.js` as ```function myFunc(tps) {return tps;}
 d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
     .words(tps)
     .rotate(0)..... ``` and the script section of my HTML as ``` 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            tps = myFunc({{tps|safe}});
           </script> ```. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tps should be a dictionary {...}, not a list [...]. In `{{ tps | safe }}` change `safe` to `tojson`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you need to create a view function (a route) in the flask backend with url like this `/get_dictionary`. This function can look like this:

from flask import request, jsonify
...

```
@app.route('/get_dictionary'):
def get_dictionary():
    ...
    your_dictionary = []
    # Fill in your_dictionary with data
    ...
    render_template('your_template.html', your_dictionary=your_dictionary)
```

EDIT:

You can pass the data from flask to script section of the html template using standard jinja2 notation:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    your_dictionary = {{ your_dictionary | tojson }}
    <!-- Do what you need with your_dictionary -->
  </script>  
  ...
</head>
...
```

Comment: I may not explained the issue correctly. What I want to do is pass a variable to a javascript instead of to an HTML document. We can pass a variable `foo` to HTML by placing `{{ foo|safe }}` into HTML, but how do I do that if the javascript, to which I want to pass the variable `foo`, is part of the `<script>` tag e.g. `<script src="{{url_for('.static', filename='js/medley.js')}}"></script>`. Here, I want to pass a variable to `medley.js`.

Comment: @bluetooth I edited the answer. You can send data to the inside script tag of the html template as usual using standard jinja2 notation. If that does not solve your problem then look at this post which probably has already answered your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but that did not work. So, I tried the suggestion in the link you provided but that did not work either. I just added a comment to my question so explain that. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can try define a var in your template html, like this:

```
<script>
        var your_var = '{{ value }}'
</script>
```

then use "your_var" in external js file. But please make sure above definition is at ahead of your js file refer.

Answer (score 0):

So Flask does have a way to do this, but it's kind of hacky and took forever for me to finally find and figure out the solution- I was having this problem too.

There's 3 parts to this:

1. Get the dictionary information in Python
2. Embed the data into your webpage
3. Access that data from your JavaScript/TypeScript code

### Step 1

#### Setup the Python dictionary for external use

Somewhere in your Flask code in either the `__init__.py` file, the `routes.py` file, or some other similarly accessible file, have the following setup:

```py
all = {"some":"random data"}

@server.context_processor
def inject_data() -> dict:
    # .context_processor information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336023/8705841
    flask_data = {'all',
                  'the',
                  'python',
                  'variables',
                  'you',
                  'want',
                  'in',
                  'your',
                  'js_or_ts'}
    # Create a dictionary from a list of variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496018/8705841
    return {'flask_data': dict(((k, eval(k)) for k in flask_data))}
```

The `@server` part should match the name of your Flask app variable (instantiated with `server = Flask(__name__)`) and does not particularly matter (usually it's called `app`). The `flask_data` dict/list should have all the Python variables you want ported over to the front end, but with quotes around them- the `eval` part of the return will grab the Python variable that matches the input string `k`.

### Step 2

#### Make the data available on the webpage

In your `index.html` page, inside the `<head>` tag (next to your other `<script>` tags, have this tag as well:

```html
<head>
    <!-- a whole bunch of stuff -->
    
    <!-- get all the Flask variables from Python -> TypeScript -->
    <script id=flask_data type="text/json">{{ flask_data|tojson }}</script>
    
    <!-- possibly a whole bunch more stuff -->
</head>
```

*Basically every single StackOverflow post even mentioning Flask has the above copy-pasted.*

### Step 3

#### Access the data from any of your JavaScript files

This is the part that no one else talked about- actually using your data from within your JavaScript (or TypeScript) code, regardless of your directory setup. It's a little hacky, but basically you access the HTML element that has your embedded data and then parse it for use in your program however you want. This is technically TypeScript code, but should work for both JavaScript and TypeScript (it took a ton of trial and error to finally get it to work on my TypeScript build).

```js
foo() {
    const flask_data = JSON.parse((document.querySelector('#flask_data') as HTMLElement).textContent || "");
    this.version = flask_data.version
    const my_flask_var = flask_data.my_flask_var;
    console.log("Data: " + flask_data);
    console.log("Variable: " + my_flask_var);
    console.log("Running verison '" + this.version + "'");
    
    if (my_flask_var === "some value") {
        do_something();
    else {
    do_something_else();
        return my_flask_var;
    }
}
// the rest of your program, using any part of the flask_data dictionary however you need
// .
// .
// .
```